# Unwanted gap appears between GridSplitters

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, gridsplitter

I want to prevent a gap from appearing in my wpf window without modifying the behavior of the remaining splitters. Please note that the longest vertical splitter is supposed to be able to slide to the left; I just don’t want the gap to appear when it is moved. A comment has been added to the GridSplitters that make up the undesired gap. How do I prevent the gap from appearing? My XAML code is listed below:

```
 <Window x:Class="MyAdvancedGrid.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" 
            Height="480" 
            Width="600">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="2" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Background="Black"
                          Height="5" /> <!-- A gap involves this splitter.-->
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Background="Black"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="5"/> <!-- A gap appears between this and the splitter above when this vertical splitter is moved to the left.-->
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          Grid.RowSpan="1"
                          Background="Black"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Width="5"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Disregard this question. I found the answer. Replacing "HorizontalAlignment="Left"" with "HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"" in the middle GridSplitter produces the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your horizontal splitter is only spanning 2 columns.

If you want the horizontal splitter to span all 3 columns (left of the tall vertical splitter), then you should put it in Column 1, and make the ColumnSpan be 3.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="1" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      Background="Black"
                      Height="5" /> <!-- see changes above.-->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Grid.RowSpan="2"
                      Background="Black"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Width="5"/> 
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      Grid.RowSpan="1"
                      Background="Black"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Width="5"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image]